# R - Find lowest/highest level in a hierarchy, within group_by

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, hierarchy

Let's say we have a table of food products:

```
product_id <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
name <- c("Cheddar", "Cheddar", "Apple", "Apple", "Pizza", "Pizza")
category <- c("Dairy", "Cheese", "Food", "Fruit", "Food", NA)
products <- data.frame(product_id, name, category)
```

[image]

With categories set up in an irregular hierarchy:

```
level_1 <- c("Food", "Food", "Food", "Food", "Food")
level_2 <- c(NA, "Dairy", "Dairy", "Fruit", "Pizza")
level_3 <- c(NA, NA, "Cheese", NA, NA)
categories <- data.frame(level_1, level_2, level_3)
```

[image]

My eventual goal is to delete duplicate products, keeping the lowest hierarchy level (i.e. more detail).

[image]

I don't necessarily need to keep the *row* with the most detail, just the label. So we could also just apply the most detailed category name to all rows in the group, and I can choose the row to remove later. **But** keep in mind there could be errors: we might have a row of `Pizza = Fruit` and `Pizza = Pizza`, which should just be ignored (that would need a manual fix).

---

Edit: The answers so far have been great, thank you for the help. There's just one thing missing from them:

In my real-world data I have errors in category, so I'm ignoring duplicates that are in different sections of the hierarchy tree. Imagine there's another section of this hierarchy for `clothing > pants > jeans`. Then if I had these product duplicates:

```
+---------+----------+
| Product | Category | 
+---------+----------+
|  Apple  |   Food   |
+---------+----------+
|  Apple  |   Jeans  |
+---------+----------+
```

I wouldn't want to keep "Jeans", even though it's a more specific category.

The only solution I can think of is this (and I don't know how to implement it in R):

- Put every level of hierarchy on the products table, and populate based on category
- Group by product
- Check that all rows in group match at level_1
- If yes, check level_2, if yes check level_3
- At each stage, if the mismatch is due to an NA, we have a winner and apply the existing category at that level
- If the mismatch is due to different categories, leave it

Alternatively, a solution could be a new column for the "highest-level common category", if that's an easier way to think about it.

---

Edit #2 - New datasets

```
product_id <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2)
name <- c("Cheddar", "Cheddar", "Apple", "Apple", "Pizza", "Pizza", "Apple")
category <- c("Dairy", "Cheese", "Food", "Fruit", "Food", NA, "Jeans")
products <- data.frame(product_id, name, category)
```

[image]

```
level_1 <- c("Food", "Food", "Food", "Food", "Food","Clothing", "Clothing", "Clothing")
level_2 <- c(NA, "Dairy", "Dairy", "Fruit", "Pizza", NA, "Pants", "Pants")
level_3 <- c(NA, NA, "Cheese", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Jeans")
categories <- data.frame(level_1, level_2, level_3)
```

[image]

Goal:

[image]

OR

[image]

Comment: Could you share a data sample including your mismatch problem stated in your recent edit?

Comment: That's actually not that simple... I'm thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

We can pivot to 'long' format, `arrange` the rows in the correct order

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
newdat <- categories %>%
              pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = 'product_id',
                       values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
              distinct  %>%
              arrange(factor(product_id, levels = rev(names(categories))))
```

use that to `match` and `slice` the second dataset 'products' after grouping by 'product_id', 'name'

```
products %>%
   group_by(product_id, name) %>% 
   slice(na.omit(match(newdat$value, category))[1])
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   product_id, name [3]
#  product_id name    category
#       <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   
#1          1 Cheddar Cheese  
#2          2 Apple   Fruit   
#3          3 Pizza   Food
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr`/`tidyr` option could be

```r
products %>%
  mutate(level = case_when(category %in% level_1 ~ 1,
                           category %in% level_2 ~ 2,
                           category %in% level_3 ~ 3
                           )) %>%
  group_by(product_id) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  slice_max(level)
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   product_id [3]
  product_id name    category level
       <dbl> <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>
1          1 Cheddar Cheese       3
2          2 Apple   Fruit        2
3          3 Pizza   Food         1
```